# Forcing Windows to show "unknown publisher" warning for unsigned application

Tags: windows-10, code-signing

I have signed an executable with a code signing certificate. I want to test whether it successfully bypasses the "unknown publisher" warning on Windows 10.

Unfortunately my original unsigned executable doesn't trigger the warning on my machine so I can't see whether the signing makes a difference!

How can I force Windows to show the "unknown publisher" warning for my unsigned executable?

Comment: Is this application marked for running ``asAdmin``?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure? The executable does not require elevated privileges to run.

Comment: The only warnings I'm aware of are "User Account Control" warnings if the EXE is marked for admin, or if the EXE has the 'downloaded from the Internet' tag. Sounds like it's the second case.

Comment: I'm not referring to "[from another computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1579225/manually-mark-executable-as-from-another-computer-on-windows-10)". Is the "unknown publisher" warning only shown for executables that require admin?

Comment: Make sure your EXE is explicitly manifested for ``asInvoker`` and ideally has the various appcompat GUIDs as well. Otherwise it may be getting some behavior added based on appcompat logic via PCA ("Program Compatibility Assistant").  See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/). Code-signing it as well is also a good thing, but only if it's not self-signed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm testing with Code signing Certificate, I noticed the behavior you said.

These are the conclusions at least in my scenario:

1. Any executable compiled in VS has the ability to bypass the Security Warning on the PC that compiled it or another one (any PC). Yes, it's amazing that you don't have to pay for an expensive EV certificate.
2. The Security Warning only appears when you distribute the EXE on any website, email and someone else downloads it. You will then be able to see the Security Warning window.
3. A good way to distribute an EXE without being signed and maintain the ability to bypass security is sharing zipped.
4. The browser is responsible for making the EXE "dangerous".